# Virtual OnScreenKeyboard in Silverlight

Tags: silverlight, on-screen-keyboard

I'm trying to build an OnScreenKeyboard to fill Textboxes in a Silverlight Web Application. The Keyboard has to be multilingual so that when I have set the language to chinese and enter a small letter like an "a",  a combobox has to appear with the chinese signs.

The OSK under Windows XP is too small for the touchscreen which I'm using.

I already built a Keyboard with Buttons that contain strings but they do not simulate the Keypress Event like a real Keyboard.

Is there a similar function like System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys for Silverlight? This is only usable in Windows.Forms which I can not use in Silverlight.

I'm working with Expression Blend 3 and Visual Studio 2008.(Silverlight Version 3)

I would be very glad for some help.

Regards Knut

Answer (score 0):

Here is an article describes how to attached Kyeboard behavior to UI controls http://www.orktane.com/Blog/post/2009/11/09/Virtual-Input-Keyboard-Behaviours-for-Silverlight.aspx

Comment: Hi Mia, thanks alot for your answer. I already tried the virtual Keyboard from orktane which was in your post but It wasnt really multilingual. I need one where I can get chinese characters when typing in a textbox.

Comment: I presume witch Chinese its gets fun, but you should be able to change culture and achieve that behavior. Have you tried, what were the results?

Comment: Thank you for your reply!                                          I changed the Keyboard Input language to chinese and clicked the textbox. Typing in a small "a" with my normal Keyboard got me a listbox with chinese chars. But with the virtual Keyboard nothing happened.